# Include type-overs in Code Snippets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1

When using XCode, I find the Code Snippets window to be very useful for dragging common code snippets into the editor. It's easy enough to add snippets, but I don't know how to make my custom snippets include type-overs (placeholder informative text that you type over). For example here is an included snippet for switch

[image]

Suppose I am adding a custom snippet for notifications. I can leave the parameter types empty like this, but I'd love to be able to include the type-overs.

[image]

If you double click on a snippet, you can select edit which lists a few actions. I'm not going to lie, some of them are vague. It's possible that the ability to do this lies on that screen but I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify a type-over parameter like so:

<#type-over-text#>

So for my notifications example it would be:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:<#notificationString#>
                                                  object:<#object#>
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  NSDictionary *dictionary = note.userInfo;
                                              }];
```

You can type this in your code, then highlight your code and drag it into the library or you can double click a code snippet then enter edit mode and type it in there.

Comment: As of this date, I've found snippet edit mode to be very buggy. For non-trival changes, I usually opt to copy-paste the text out. When finished, I either copy it back in, or just recreate the snippet.